# how to find a single field in mongoDB instead of entire document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to achieve the result as obtained by

```
SELECT AGE FROM COLL WHERE NAME="AYUSH";
```

I took the following approach

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("new");
  //var query = { name:'ayush' };
  //var age = {age : 1, _id:0};
  dbo.collection("coll").find( 
       { name:'ayush' },
       { age : 1, _id:0}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

the result that i am getting is

```
[ { _id: 5a818b71d2029813505d736a,
name: 'ayush',
age: '22',
sex: 'm' } ]
```

Comment: Have you tried projecting using the [**`project`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) cursor method, like `dbo.collection("coll").find({ name:'ayush' }).project({age : 1}).toArray(function(err, result) { ... }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to convert the result in to an array and then send that array as the response.

The code would look like:

```
dbo.collection("coll").find( 
       { name:'ayush' },
       { age : 1, _id:0}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var array = [];
    array.push(result[0].age);
    res.send(array);});
```

Moreover don't use mongoClient,use mongoose instead.its easier and better

Answer (score 3):

From MongoDB documentation : [**Project Fields to Return from Query**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

> **Return the Specified Fields and the _id Field Only**
>
> A projection can explicitly include several fields by setting the
>   `<field>` to `1` in the projection document. The following operation
>   returns all documents that match the query. In the result set, only
>   the `item, status` and, by default, the `_id` fields return in the
>   matching documents.
>
> `db.inventory.find( { status: "A" }, { item: 1, status: 1 } )`
>
> The operation corresponds to the following SQL statement:
>
> `SELECT _id, item, status from inventory WHERE status = "A"`

In your case, if you only want the field `age`, you have to suppress the other fields `_id`, `name` and `sex` as following :

```
dbo.collection("coll").find({ name:'ayush' },{age:1, _id:0, name:0, sex:0})...
```